# AWS S3 Gzip Extremely Slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, gzip

I have a big file 200GB sitting on the S3 instance and I am thinking about moving it to my local to do some work. My thought is to gzip the file first and then scp to my local machine to reduce the cost of IO for S3 and also save some time.

However, the gzip step in S3 is taking ages. 
My thought is that the S3 is actually a big disk, and somehow, the data is actually flowing back to and EC2 and then move back to S3 and the IO is taking too much time.

I am wondering how could I get around that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 is not really a big disk. There are layers that can make it look like one, but it ultimately does not operate as one. With a disk you read and write blocks, with s3, you read/write entire objects.

I'm guessing you are trying to do this with s3fs, which copies files locally (into /tmp) before doing any operations on them.